My Jenkins job failed with Timeout error and local System getting Lag and Generate Heat
I have created an node agent and executed 6 maven jobs parallelly each job can run one testng.xml file

Issue 1: After sometime of execution my local system getting and generate more heat
Issue 2: After running more than 3hrs each node build failed with time out error and most of my testcases were skipped

here is the log
[ERROR] com.cloudlex.testcases.IntakeDetailForms.PIAndPremises.PiAndPremisesClientDetailsTest.beforeClass -- Time elapsed: 300.3 s <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: 
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 150.000
  (Session info: chrome=131.0.6778.86)
Build info: version: '4.12.1', revision: '8e34639b11'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [7097c3b3a92d5aad2ac3f295e01e4bc6, refresh {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 131.0.6778.86, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 131.0.6778.87 (ce31cae94873..., userDataDir: C:\Windows\SystemTemp\scope...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60046}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:60046/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 131.0.6778.86, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 7097c3b3a92d5aad2ac3f295e01e4bc6
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:602)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:675)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:679)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteNavigation.refresh(RemoteWebDriver.java:1101)
    at com.cloudlex.testcases.IntakeDetailForms.PIAndPremises.PiAndPremisesClientDetailsTest.beforeClass(PiAndPremisesClientDetailsTest.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:69)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:361)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:296)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:180)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:471)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil.lambda$execute$0(ThreadUtil.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? how to solve my issue?
